# Why can't Windows 10 see HDD image on KVM?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I used [this](http://www.funtoo.org/Windows_7_Virtualization_with_KVM) tutorial.

I created a 32Gb `.img` file for Windows. I started to install with the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa 
DISKIMG=~/QEMU_machines/Windows10/win10.img
WIN10IMG=~/Downloads/Win10_1607_English_x64.iso
VIRTIMG=~/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.126.iso
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -drive format=raw,file=${DISKIMG},if=virtio -m 2048 \
-net nic,model=virtio -net user -cdrom ${WIN10IMG} \
-drive format=raw,file=${VIRTIMG},index=3,media=cdrom \
-rtc base=localtime,clock=host -smp cores=2,threads=2 \
-usbdevice tablet -soundhw ac97 -cpu host -vga vmware
```

But it doesn't see any HDD's during installation (but it does exist - I've seen it in the directory):
[image]

Also, Windows installer says that VirtIO drivers (from [here](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/archive-virtio/virtio-win-0.1.126-2/)) aren't signed, so I can't install them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using graphical tool called `virt-manager` there no such problem.

```
sudo apt-get install virt-manager -y
sudo usermod -a -G libvirtd <username>
systemctl start libvirtd
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
```

Comment: Does that file really need 777 permissions?